# Edit the coordinates of Geotiff file

Tags: gis, tiff, projection, gdal, geotiff

I dont have much knowledge with GIS.
I need help with editing the coordinates of a GeoTiff file.

For eg, these are the corner coordinates of a file:

`Upper Left  (  62.0000000,  47.0000000) ( 62d 0' 0.00"E, 47d 0' 0.00"N)`

`Lower Left  (  62.0000000,  39.7103806) ( 62d 0' 0.00"E, 39d42'37.37"N)`

How do I change these to these? so as to reposition the file.

`Upper Left  (  69.2896194,  47.0000000) ( 69d17'22.63"E, 47d 0' 0.00"N)`

`Lower Left  (  69.2896194,  39.7103806) ( 69d17'22.63"E, 39d42'37.37"N)`

Any help will would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this but it might be possible using [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) and the [`-te bbox`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-te) option. You'll need to look up the right hand edge (XMAX)

```
gdalwarp -te 69.2896194 XMAX 39.7103806 47.0000000 src.tif dest.tif
```

Comment: i fit worked please accept the answer for the benefit of others coming later

Comment: I found that the solution has a issue, data gets corrupted. gdal_translate seems to work nicely.

Comment: If you have Python, consider using `gdal_edit`: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html
That way you can *only* edit the metadata in-place, without touching the data. It will also be way faster compared to copying the data (with `gdalwarp`, or `gdal_translate`).